# Correct Ruchi krut Pitra stotra in sanskrit and the benefits of chanting everyday

Tags: scripture, vedas, stotra, pitru, vedic-chanting

Please let me know Ruchi krut Pitra stotra in sanskrit and English transliteration. Also the benefits of chanting everyday. [image][image]

Comment: I know about a Vyasa Krit Pitru Stotra. Can you post the opening verses of the Stotra you are mentioning about?

Comment: @Rickross- added picture in question

Comment: Thanks .. it says Ruchira Uvacha .. who is Ruchira? Also are Ruchi and Ruchira the same?

Comment: @Rickross- Not sure who is Ruchira.

Comment: Okay but Ruchira is the one who is saying this Stotra.

Comment: @Rickross: yes he is the person who has made this stotra